# Change the way edits in the grace period work

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, edits

Right now if you edit a post during the grace period the following will happen:

- The post is silently changed without any notice (such as "last edited 1 min ago")
- The added/removed/changed text is not available in the revision history (there is no revision entry at all)
- The question is not bumped to the top of the activity page
- The edit doesn't count towards the auto-CW limit and is ineligible for certain badges (such as Strunk & White).

Now, the last 2 points are totally fine but the first two [cause a **great** deal of confusion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40253/bug-report-so-says-i-made-a-change-that-i-didnt-make) to both experienced and new users.

**I propose that every edit made in the grace period adds a new revision and triggers the "last edited" notification on the post body**, while not bumping the question or count towards the CW limit.

This has several advantages:

- It follows the principle of least astonishment. The observable behavior of every edit is the same.
- It allows us to read past revisions (for curiosity or other reasons)
- In general, it will cause much less confusion

In fact, I don't really see any advantage of the current approach.. Maybe less cluttering on the revision page? Does it really matter? I don't think so

Comment: Note that this (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39635/add-an-indication-that-a-post-has-been-edited-in-the-5-minutes-grace-period) is related, **but not a duplicate**! (I also proposed the very same thing in a comment there)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Maybe less cluttering on the revision page?

That. I'll sometimes make a half-dozen or more tiny edits within that grace period, everything from fixing minor formatting or spelling issues to re-writing awkward sentences (or occasionally, entire paragraphs...) that I missed during my pre-submit proof-reading. Is there any real benefit to holding onto such information?

...and... Is there any *real* down-side to throwing it away? If you need the revision history to remember what changes you *just made* to someone else's post, then maybe you should be spending more time entering revision comments before submitting...

> Does it really matter?

If I come back a day, month, or year later and make a major revision to a post, quickly followed by the usual half-dozen *minor* revisions, what are the chances anyone viewing the revision history cares about seeing anything but the difference between the current revision and the one that was active 10 minutes ago? Remember, [there's currently no easy way to compare non-consecutive revisions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15635/show-the-diff-between-two-non-consecutive-revisions-of-a-post)...

Here's a thought: if you must edit something that's been posted or edited less than 5 minutes ago, then after submitting your changes, **check the revision history before you wander off**! This is a good idea *anyway*, since someone else may have submitted an edit as you were submitting yours, and although that *will* show up in the revision history you'll still have stomped on a (potentially-valuable) change. If your revision contains changes you didn't intend to make, then edit it and correct the problem... within the grace period on *your* edit! Remember, there's no information truly *lost* here - if you removed something accidentally, it'll still be in the revision history where you can find and restore it.

It also doesn't hurt to leave a comment when you plan to make significant changes to a post and think someone else might wish to do the same... You can then remove the comment when you're done.

Note that a less dramatic (though still technically-challenging, I'm sure) change would be to improve the handling of edit collisions such that [edits within the grace period and edits submitted near-simultaneously are detected reliably](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22135/optimistic-concurrency-for-post-edits/36985#36985).

#### See also:

- [How to avoid edit collisions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20658/how-to-avoid-edit-collisions)
- [Suggestion: block edits by others in the 5 minute window after creating a post or doing an edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26184/suggestion-block-edits-by-others-in-the-5-minute-window-after-creating-a-post-or)

Comment: Since March 2011, a warning is shown [after you save](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1577/notifications-for-concurrent-changes-when-editing-posts/28119#28119), if a conflict occurs.