# Comment gets appended to URL, question apparently edited with no trail

Tags: support, comments, revisions-list

Referring to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383796/time-function-in-php), I am unable to post comments. The comment gets appended to the URL and then loads the page.

Some people are also saying the question was edited just a while ago, but there is no "edited" note showing.

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [five (5) minute grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9090/is-there-an-editing-grace-period-on-answers-after-they-have-been-posted).

When I checked the post around one (1) minute after you posted, it was regarding inserting into database with PHP and asking about date related functions.

[Anthony Forloney](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2383809/revisions)'s first version answer (which is edited and deleted at the moment) tried to answer about that.

But it suddenly changed to HTML codes. That's why people are saying it was edited, but you've edited within the 5 minute grace period. So there is no record for that.

Comment: what is that for?

Comment: there is some discussion about grace period here, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40257/ and its related questions part