# When multiple edits are coalesced, does that mean only one bump?

Tags: support, edits, bump, grace-period

If I write an answer, then edit it 4 minutes later, it doesn't show up as edited. Does it still bump the question?

Similarly, if I edit my answer, and then re-edit it again 4 minutes later, it only shows up as one edit in the history;<sup>*</sup> does it bump the question once, or twice?

At least on SO's front page and more active tags, a question could easily have fallen pretty deep in 4 minutes, and I don't want to accidentally drag it back to the top just to fix a typo in my last edit.

---

<sub>* As a side note, what is this edit-coalescing feature called? Obviously not "edit coalescing", because searching for "coalesce edit" or "edit coalescing" only turns up 5 results, only one of which refers to this feature…</sub>

Comment: It's called "editing during the grace period".

Comment: @AnnaLear: Ah, thanks. Now that I know what to search for, it looks like [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40257/change-the-way-edits-in-the-grace-period-work) has the answer right there in the question (unless things have changed in the past 5 years).

Comment: Dupe contains answer for your question: *Edits on a post within 5 minutes of its creation or another revision-generating edit fold the changes back into the previous revision, and do not cause the post to be bumped*

Answer (score 4):

No, if you edit during the grace period, it doesn't bump the post. Only edits that create a new revision do.